# Quickly getting to YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS in Perl

Tags: perl, datetime, formatting, timestamp

When writing Perl scripts I frequently find the need to obtain the current time represented as a string formatted as `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS` (say `2009-11-29 14:28:29`).

In doing this I find myself taking this quite cumbersome path:

- `man perlfunc`
- `/localtime` to search for localtime - repeat five times (`/` + `\n`) to reach the relevant section of the manpage
- Copy the string `($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime(time);` from the manpage to my script.
- Try with `my $now = sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", $year, $mon, $mday, $hour, $min, $sec);`
- Remember gotcha #1: Must add 1900 to $year to get current year.
- Try with `my $now = sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", $year+1900, $mon, $mday, $hour, $min, $sec);`
- Remember gotcha #2: Must add 1 to $mon to get current month.
- Try with `my $now = sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", $year+1900, $mon+1, $mday, $hour, $min, $sec);`
- Seems ok. Done!

While the process outlined above works it is far from optimal. I'm sure there is a smarter way, so my question is simply:

**What is the easiest way to obtain a `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS` of the current date/time in Perl?**

Where "easy" encompasses both "easy-to-write" and "easy-to-remember".

Comment: You should have written a subroutine to search the perlfunc and remember the gotchas for you, of course!

Comment: Write a stackoverflow question with all the steps, pretending to ask for a solution :-)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Use `strftime` in the standard [`POSIX`](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html) module. The arguments to [`strftime`](https://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html#strftime) in Perl’s binding were designed to align with the return values from [`localtime`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) and [`gmtime`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/gmtime.html). Compare

```
strftime(fmt, sec, min, hour, mday, mon, year, wday = -1, yday = -1, isdst = -1)
```

with

```
my          ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,     $yday,     $isdst) = gmtime(time);
```

Example command-line use is

```
$ perl -MPOSIX -le 'print strftime "%F %T", localtime $^T'
```

or from a source file as in

```
use POSIX;

print strftime "%F %T", localtime time;
```

Some systems do not support the `%F` and `%T` shorthands, so you will have to be explicit with

```
print strftime "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime time;
```

or

```
print strftime "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime time;
```

Note that [`time`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/time.html) returns the current time when called whereas [`$^T`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24BASETIME) is fixed to the time when your program started. With [`gmtime`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/gmtime.html), the return value is the current time in GMT. Retrieve time in your local timezone with [`localtime`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html).

Comment: There is also strftime in Time::Piece (core since 5.10) which lets you use a more object oriented form (see my answer below).  Also, $^T (time since program start) is not what you want.

Answer (score 39):

Why not use the `DateTime` module to do the dirty work for you? It's easy to write *and* remember!

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime;

my $dt   = DateTime->now;   # Stores current date and time as datetime object
my $date = $dt->ymd;   # Retrieves date as a string in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format
my $time = $dt->hms;   # Retrieves time as a string in 'hh:mm:ss' format

my $wanted = "$date $time";   # creates 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' string
print $wanted;
```

Once you know what's going on, you can get rid of the temps and save a few lines of code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime;

my $dt = DateTime->now;
print join ' ', $dt->ymd, $dt->hms;
```

Answer (score 35):

Try this:

```
use POSIX qw/strftime/;
print strftime('%Y-%m-%d',localtime);
```

the `strftime` method does the job effectively for me. Very simple and efficient.

---

Answer (score 14):

[Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Time-Piece) (in core since Perl 5.10) also has a strftime function and by default overloads localtime and gmtime to return Time::Piece objects:

```
use Time::Piece;
print localtime->strftime('%Y-%m-%d');
```

or without the overridden localtime:

```
use Time::Piece (); 
print Time::Piece::localtime->strftime('%F %T');
```

Comment: +1 for the mention of a core module and usage -- since the vast amount of available modules are one of the major reasons most of us  use Perl in the first place

Answer (score 10):

I made a little test (Perl v5.20.1 under FreeBSD in VM) calling the following blocks 1.000.000 times each:

A

```
my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime(time);
my $now = sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", $year+1900, $mon+1, $mday, $hour, $min, $sec);
```

B

```
my $now = strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S',localtime);
```

C

```
my $now = Time::Piece::localtime->strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S');
```

with the following results:

A: 2 seconds

B: 11 seconds

C: 19 seconds

This is of course not a thorough test or benchmark, but at least it is reproducable for me, so even though it is more complicated, I'd prefer the first method if generating a datetimestamp is required very often.

Calling (eg. under FreeBSD 10.1)

```
my $now = `date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S" | tr -d "\n"`;
```

might not be such a good idea because it is not OS-independent and takes quite some time.

Best regards,
Holger

Answer (score 6):

if you just want a human readable time string and not that exact format:

```
$t = localtime;
print "$t\n";
```

prints

```
Mon Apr 27 10:16:19 2015
```

or whatever is configured for your locale.

Answer (score 4):

`Time::Piece::datetime()` can eliminate `T`.

```
use Time::Piece;
print localtime->datetime(T => q{ });
```

Comment: another mention of Time::Piece should make me remember it now -- not exactly the easiest module to remember to use if not used on a daily basis :)

Answer (score 2):

Short and sweet, no additional modules needed:

```
my $toDate = `date +%m/%d/%Y" "%l:%M:%S" "%p`;
```

Output for example would be: 04/25/2017  9:30:33 AM

Comment: `date +%Y-%m-%d" "%H:%M:%S` to get the exact format needed by OP

Comment: Doesn't work when called out of windows command line, does it? Windows version of "date" has different behaviour.

Comment: My answer was based on Perl running on a Unix system, so it may not apply to windows versions of Perl. So you didn't get this result running Perl on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

In many cases, the needed 'current time' is rather $^T, which is the time at which the script started running, in whole seconds (assuming only 60 second minutes) since the UNIX epoch.

This to prevent that an early part of a script uses a different date (or daylight-saving status) than a later part of a script, for example in query-conditions and other derived values.

For that variant of 'current time', one can use a constant, also to document that it was frozen at compile time:

```
use constant YMD_HMS_AT_START => POSIX::strftime( "%F %T", localtime $^T );
```

Alternative higher resolution startup time:

```
0+ [ Time::HiRes::stat("/proc/$$") ]->[10]
```